# Decorator for Spree::Variant

Tags: ruby-on-rails, spree

I am writing a Spree extension where a model creates a one-to-one relation with `Spree::Variant`. I have created the following decorator:

```
# app/models/spree/variant_decorator.rb
Spree::Variant.class_eval do
  has_one :persomodel, class_name: 'Extension::Persomodel'
end
```

I found out that this decorator is not evaluated by running the `console`. Looking at the `Variant` model in `spree_core` (version 2.0.3), I saw that there is no file `app/model/variant.rb`, just a file `app/model/variant/scope.rb`. I guess this is the reason why my decorator is not evaluated.

How can I then implement the relation I am looking for, please ?

Comment: The appropriate file should be at https://github.com/spree/spree/blob/v2.0.3/core/app/models/spree/variant.rb

Comment: Thank you, your input was helpful. I overlooked this file for some reason...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not sure your conclusion is correct.

In a Spree app one typically includes a section similar to the following in the application.rb

```
config.to_prepare do
  ['../app/**/*_decorator*.rb'].each do |glob|
    Dir.glob(File.join(File.dirname(__FILE__), glob)) do |c|
      Rails.configuration.cache_classes ? require(c) : load(c)
    end
  end
end
```

This iterates over all files of the form *_decorator*.rb in the app directory and requires/loads them as needed.

If you're building an extension as a Rails engine, you would put a similar block:

```
 Dir.glob(File.join(File.dirname(__FILE__), "../../app/**/*_decorator*.rb")) do |c|
   Rails.configuration.cache_classes ? require(c) : load(c)
 end
```

in the config.to_prepare block in the engine.rb

Do you have the appropriate code in the config.to_prepare block as appropriate for your project?  If it is present then your code should be evaluated.

Comment: Hi Peter, you are right. I added the code you recommended to my engine.rb file, now the association works perfectly. I had already seen this inclusion mechanism, but was not really awarer of it. Your answer helped me, I learned something. Many many thanks for your valuable help !